# ¿Por qué al depurar no me salen las tildes en VS Code?

Tags: vscode

Al incluir el encabezado  y utilizar la funcion setlocale en dev c++ me funcionaban las tildes y la ñ,pero en vs code no, quisiera que me ayuden.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habrías de verificar si la codificación del proyecto es la correcta. Para mostrar correctamente los acentos y otros caracteres especiales tiene que estar en **UTF-8**, y por tu imagen verifico que lo tienes en **Windows 1252**.

Está explicado [aquí: https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/8274020](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/8274020)

Saludos,
ealcober.

Answer (score 2):

En la esquina inferior derecha verás la codificación del archivo, lo más probable es que la tengas en **utf-8**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar el problema tienes que cambiarla. Clicas ahí, ahora "Reopen with encoding" y seleccionas, por ejemplo, **Western Windows 1252**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora te aparecerán una caracteres raros en inversión, esto se produce por el cambio de codificación, pero no pasa nada, los corriges, compilas, ejecutas y listo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]